# "View As MIME Type" in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, mime-types

Is there any way to force either Firefox or Chrome to interpret a loaded resource as a particular MIME type?

For example, the raw code views provided by online SCC interfaces such as Google Code send content as `text/plain` by default. If I'm looking at an HTML file, I'd like to be able to override this in the browser and view it as `text/html`.

Are there any extensions or hidden commands for Firefox or Chrome that provide "View as MIME type" functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Firefox, there is an add-on provides almost the function you wanted: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/force-content-type/ . No idea if there is a Chrome extension or not.

Even if the functionality exists, I wouldn't recommend you to use it in your example: Arbitrary HTML would have access to google.com domain for cookie and script, which is really really bad in terms of security.

Comment: Very good point about security. Fortunately, it looks like Google has thought of that. All raw files are served from *projectname*.googlecode.com, which does not set or transmit any cookies. (The code browser is served from code.google.com, which does use cookies.)

Answer (score 29):

Shameless plug: I just published a (free) Chrome extension to do just what you ask. It's available on the [Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpfpbhhpecfkhkmponbmaldhfollibde). It works by listening to the `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` event and patching in a custom `content-type` HTTP header. If you'd like the build it yourself or see how it's implemented, [the source is available on GitHub](https://github.com/atdt/chrome-force-media-type/blob/master/force-media-type/media-type.js).

Comment: Ori, this is excellent. I've been using this extension almost daily.

Comment: Looks that you can only activate this functionality if you right click on a link and select the option "open as media type".  Can I change the mime type of a file wich URL I have but I don't have a page pointing at?

Comment: Just a minor criticism: your extension seems to remove the `filename` parameter from `Content-Disposition` if it's present, which I suspect would result in the default filename being lost if the user tries to save the page/document.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli I created a temporary index.html page with the links I wanted to load as HTML and then right clicked those :) Only need to do this once.

Comment: Your “[Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpfpbhhpecfkhkmponbmaldhfollibde)” link is broken, both here and on GitHub. Searching for “force media type” in the store shows only an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-content-type/jnfofbopfpaoeojgieggflbpcblhfhka) called “Modify Content-Type”. Not sure if it’s yours.

Answer (score -4):

Ubuntu 12.04 has an extension to the System Settings called Tweak. This has a FileType Manager.